# How should I switch view(SP,PC) in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I use Laravel4, I did following code.

```
#global.php

View::addNamespace('pc', base_path('pc'));
View::addNamespace('sp', base_path('sp'));
```

,

```
#TestController

function sample()
{
    if ($this->isPC()) {
        $namespace = 'pc';
    } else {
        $namespace = 'sp';
    }
    return View::make($namespace . '::sample');
}
```

How should I do using Laravel 5?

Comment: Does the logic of how the application works change if pc vs other or is it just the display that changes?

Comment: I'd like to use UserAgent.

Comment: ok that still doesn't answer the question.